# Unable to find dynamic value of Voucher number on the page using regex with Selenium webdriver

Tags: java, regex

In my application, when I submit a request, it generates a unique number which is dynamic all the time. I am trying to capture that number using regex. I have matched the pattern successfully but not able to get the value so that I can use it in my next step.
I am using following code but it is showing same number DK-21 again not the newly generated-

```
    String line = "The following Requisition has been submitted: DK-21";
    String pattern = "([A-Z]{2,3}-[0-9]{2,3})";

    // Create a Pattern object
    Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);

    // Now create matcher object.
    Matcher m = r.matcher(pattern);
    if (m.find( )) {
       System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group(0) );
       System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group(1) );
       System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group(2) );
    } else {
       System.out.println("NO MATCH");
    }
```

Please let me know if any have any idea about regex or how can I handle this using regex with selenium webdriver. Following number is generation in application [Application output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HcHlI.png)

Also tried following code -

```
  //String requisitionno = "The following Requisition has been submitted: ([A-Z]{2,3}-[0-9]{2,3})";
 // String regexvalue = "([A-Z]{2,3}-[0-9]{2,3})";
    /*if(requisitionno.matches("The following Requisition has been submitted: ([A-Z]{2,3}-[0-9]{2,3})")){
        System.out.println("regex value"+requisitionno.matches("The following Requisition has been submitted: ([A-Z]{2,3}-[0-9]{2,3})"));

    }
    else {

        System.out.println("false");
    }

   }
```

Comment: Also tried this code - //String requisitionno = "The following Requisition has been submitted: ([A-Z]{2,3}-[0-9]{2,3})";
    // String regexvalue = "([A-Z]{2,3}-[0-9]{2,3})";
     /*if(requisitionno.matches("The following Requisition has been submitted: ([A-Z]{2,3}-[0-9]{2,3})")){
      System.out.println("regex value"+requisitionno.matches("The following Requisition has been submitted: ([A-Z]{2,3}-[0-9]{2,3})"));
      
     }
     else {
      
      System.out.println("false");
     }
     
       }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer. Actually I was writing the static line so that all the time regex pattern was matching the same static content but I was required dynamic (on the page value) value. So that I had firstly used get getDriver().getPageSource(); and then matched the regex in the source.

```
    String line = getDriver().getPageSource();
    String pattern = "([A-Z]{2,3}-[0-9]{2,3})";

    // Create a Pattern object
    Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);

    // Now create matcher object.
    Matcher m = r.matcher(line);
    if (m.find( )) {
         System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group(0) );
    //   System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group(1) );
      // System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group(2) );
    } else {
       System.out.println("NO MATCH");
    }
```

So I got the Output which is dynamic every time -
Found value: DK-42

Thank you all.

Answer (score 1):

you need to match the `line` not the `pattern`!

change this line in your code:

```
// Now create matcher object.
    Matcher m = r.matcher(line);
```

Comment: But all the time I will have a line of such type on the page from which I will have to extract the number DK-xyx so how to do without line?

Comment: why do want to do it without the line?? Maybe you need to explain your exact problem a bit more. What are you trying to do? and where is the problem? (best in your question! not here in the comments)